Detect hash code change in URL with NextJS 12
I can't detect # hash code changes in URL with any of the useRouter props as useEffect dependancy:
  const { locale, asPath, basePath, pathname, route, query } = useRouter();
  const [hashCode, setHashCode] = useState<number>(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Hash code changed");
    if (asPath.split("#")) setHashCode(Number(asPath.split("#")[1]));
    else {
      setHashCode(1);
    }
  }, [asPath, pathname, basePath, route, query]);

   return (  
   <>
     <a href="1">
        Hash code 1
     </a> 
     <a href="2">
        Hash code 2
     </a> 
   </> 

How can I detect hash code in the URL has been changed and set the current hash code in a state with Next JS ?

try hashchange_event, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event
